# Hibernate & JPA - ExistsBy For Nested Object With The Same Column Name

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue in Spring boot and Hibernate when trying to use the existsBy in my JPA repository. Lets take this as an example:

I have two tables with a joined relationship:

Visit with the columns: id, name, datetime etc..
Record with the columns: visit_id, etc..

I'm trying to use the below JPA query in my record repository:

existsByVisitId

Unfortunately it does not work and the reason is probably the column name visit_id in the record repository is equal to the class name Visit with the id column.

Any ideas how to let this work ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.